# Extract Differential Interferometry from SENTINEL-1 image

Tags: remote-sensing, radar, sentinel-1, esa

I downloaded some SLC images from scihub.esa.int . And I want to extract Differencial Interferometry from them by using SNAP-ESA software.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Welcome to the site Mohamed.  From past experience, the more details you can provide (e.g. background, what research you have done, links, where you may be stuck, etc), the more likely you are to receive good answers.  You can take our tour to get up to speed on the site: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour.  Also, this post may be helpful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You may want to check the user guide of the Sentinel-1 toolbox at https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar

Answer (score 2):

InSAR on Sentinel-1 imagery would require the following steps in SNAP:

1. Data input and baseline evaluation
2. Coregistration and interferogram generation
3. Computation of coherence
4. Removal of topographic phase
5. Phase filtering (multi-looking)
6. Phase unwrapping (this is a critical task and strongly depends on the software)
7. Conversion into vertical displacement values
8. Geocoding

See also this tutorial:
http://sentinel1.s3.amazonaws.com/docs/S1TBX%20Stripmap%20Interferometry%20with%20Sentinel-1%20Tutorial.pdf